# Angular JS: Can $scope be passed to an iframe and compile iframe's content using the passed scope?

Tags: angularjs, iframe, compilation

say I have controller named "test" with:

```
$scope.testValue = "Hello World!";
```

index.html:

```
<div ng-controller="test">
    <iframe iframe-directive src="template.html"></iframe>
</div>
```

template.html:

```
{{testValue}}
```

How can the iframe directive compile it and output "Hello World" instead of "{{testValue}}"?

Comment: I am afraid you cannot share the angular context between different pages, i.e., your `index.html` and `template.html`.

Comment: You can try `templateUrl` in `ngRoute`: https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07

Comment: I've been looking for answer and found out that $compile can make it. something like $compile(elem.contents())(scope); but I just can't make it work. Is it really impossible?

Comment: holy  . . . got it working. I'm just not using the latest release of angularjs

Comment: Awesome. Could you share some JSFiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Just put this inside iframe-directive and it will work

`link: function(scope,elem,attrs) {
  $compile(elem.contents())(scope);
 }`